# Do I need to use the jobs keyword in my YAML file when only running a single job?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to set the timeoutInMinutes value for a single job within my YAML file.

At the moment I am doing it like this:

```
jobs:
- job: cypressJob
  timeoutInMinutes: 240
```

Do I need to use the `jobs` keyword or can I format it like this, since it's only a single job?:

```
- job: cypressJob
  timeoutInMinutes: 240
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won’t work, the editor in Azure DevOps try to point us at this:
[image: Invalid YAML structure]

But if you only have one job and want the shortest notation you could even leave out job.The disadvantage is that your not able to specify additional properties on that job.

In your question your are using additional properties.
In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#define-a-single-job) jobs is used in this case, also in a one job example.
I validated this and it won’t work indeed:
[image: failing pipeline]

Answer (score 0):

From your requirement, you need to set `timeoutInMinutes` value. This value needs to be defined at job level.

> Do I need to use the jobs keyword or can I format it like this, since it's only a single job?:

In this case, the `jobs` keyword is required. It's fixed syntax in Azure Devops. We must specify the jobs flag before we can define a single job.

Example:

```
jobs:
- job: Job1
  timeoutInMinutes: 10
  steps:
  - bash: echo "test"
```

Refer to this doc: [Job YAML Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-job?view=azure-pipelines)

```
jobs:
- job: string # Required as first property. ID of the job. Valid names may only contain alphanumeric characters and '_' and may not start with a number.
  displayName: string # Human-readable name for the job. 
  dependsOn: string | [ string ]  # Any jobs which must complete before this one
  condition: string # Evaluate this condition expression to determine whether to run this job. 
  continueOnError: string # Continue running even on failure?. 
  timeoutInMinutes: string # Time to wait for this job to complete before the server kills it. 
  cancelTimeoutInMinutes: string # Time to wait for the job to cancel before forcibly terminating it. 
  variables: variables # Job-specific variables
  strategy: jobStrategy # Execution strategy for this job
  pool: pool # Pool where this job will run
  container: jobContainer # Container resource name
  services:  # Container resources to run as a service container.
    string: string # Name/value pairs.
  workspace:  # Workspace options on the agent.
    clean: string # Which parts of the workspace should be scorched before fetching.  (outputs, resources, all)
  uses:  # Any resources required by this job that are not already referenced
    repositories: [ string ] # Repository references 
    pools: [ string ] # Pool references 
  steps: [ task | script | powershell | pwsh | bash | checkout | download | downloadBuild | getPackage | publish | template | restoreCache | saveCache | reviewApp ]
```